# My traefik, letsencrypt, uvicorn and docker configuration not working

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, traefik, lets-encrypt, uvicorn

I am trying to use **traefik** and **letsencrypt** to provide secure http to my **uvicorn** server running but I am having issues. Here are my configuration files

The **docker-compose.yml** file

```
services:
  traefik-certs-dumper:
        image: ldez/traefik-certs-dumper:v2.7.0
        entrypoint: sh -c '
            apk add jq
            ; while ! [ -e /data/acme.json ]
                || ! [ `jq ".Certificates | length" /data/acme.json` != 0 ]; do
                    sleep 1
                ; done
            && traefik-certs-dumper file --watch
                --source /data/acme.json --dest /data/certs'
        volumes:
• .:/data

  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7.12
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik
    environment:
      - "GODADDY_API_KEY=my-godaddy-api-key"
      - "GODADDY_API_SECRET=my-godaddy-api-secret"
server:
    container_name: my-server
    image: my-server-docker
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - uploadedFiles:/app/uploaded_files/
    environment:
      host_server: postgresqldb
      db_server_port: 5432
      database_name: my-database
      db_username: user
      db_password: password
      ssl_mode: prefer
    labels:
       -"traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.basic.port=8000"
    networks:
      - web
      - postgresqlnet
    restart: always
    depends_on:
       - database

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

The **traefik.toml** file

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "myemail@mydomain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "https"
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "godaddy"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0
  [[acme.domains]]
   main = "mydomain.com"
```

the command to run the uvicorn server in **Dockerfile**
I supplied the certificates and key already got from letsencrypt to enable me run uvicorn with the https scheme(I really don't know if this is right).
I don't know if uvicorn should be run with http or https

```
CMD ["python3.8", "-m", "uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--ssl-keyfile=./certs/private/mydomain.com.key", "--ssl-certfile=./certs/certs/mydomain.com.crt"]
```

The **logs from the server program** when started

```
my-server                  | INFO:     Started server process [1]
my-server                  | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
my-server                  | INFO:     Application startup complete.
my-server                  | INFO:     Uvicorn running on https://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

but when I access the domain name hoping it gets to traefik and then gets routed to uvicorn I get a **502 Bad Gateway** error. I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change your [labels] in  [container_name: my-server]

> traefik.enable: true
> traefik.http.routers.my-server.entrypoints: https
> traefik.http.routers.my-server.rule: Host(`<mydomain.com>`)
> traefik.http.routers.my-server.service: my-server-svc
> traefik.http.services. my-server-svc.loadbalancer.server.port: 8000
> traefik.http.routers.my-server.tls: true

uvicorn does not need https.

uvicorn [http]<->[http] Traefik [https]<->[https] INTERNET

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).